# How can I optimize an XPath expression?

Tags: xpath

Is there any way I can shorten the following condition used in an XPath expression?

```
(../parent::td or ../parent::ol or ../parent::ul)
```

The version of XPath is 1.0.

Comment: Can you show us where and how u use it?

Comment: You're asking two different questions: how can I optimize it, and how can I make it shorter. The length of the expression has very little bearing on its execution speed. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Unfortunately, I cannot. Please consider it more like a generic question.

Comment: @MichaelKay The best answer would be a shorter expression which executes quicker. However, I would not take into account the slightest differences in the execution speed (I don't work with large amounts of data). So... I think I'd rather go with shortness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest is probably

`../..[self::td|self::ol|self::ul]`

Whether there is a performance difference between "|" and "or" will depend on the processor, but I suspect that in most cases it won't be noticeable. For performance, the important thing is to put the conditions in the right order (the one most likely to return true should come first). Factoring out the navigation to the grandparent should almost certainly help performance, with the caveats (a) your XPath engine may do this optimization automatically, and (b) the difference will probably be so tiny you will have trouble measuring it.

Answer (score 1):

use the '|' operator.
`(../parent::td|../parent::ol|../parent::ul)`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter:

```
../..[self::td or self::ol or self::ul]
```

Example usage:

```
//p[../..[self::td or self::ol or self::ul]]
```